# Same Controller but Different views in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

i have made an application in asp.net mvc3/c#/Razor , now i want to implement new template for the same application and i want to use the same controller logic but views will be different how i will do this ? . For example : if some visits my site from UAE i want to to template **A** but if someone else views my site anywhere else i want to show him my template **B** . Is there any way to have same controllers but different views in asp.net mvc 3

Comment: Do you mean that the `layout` will be different?

Comment: Not only layout all views also will be change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [NuGet package](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek10NewMobileViewEnginesForASPNETMVC3SpeccompatibleWithASPNETMVC4.aspx) for you. And in ASP.NET MVC 4 it's built-in. This package tests the user agent in order to serve mobile versions of the views. It implements a custom view engine for this. It could be extended so that instead of using the user agent you use the Request.UserHostAddress (IP) in order to dispatch to the proper folder. As far as the mapping between the user IP and a country is concerned, well, that's something you will have to implement yourself or use an existing public API.

Comment: Any Implementation or tutorial of Custom view engine ?

Comment: Yeah, there are many out there. Just Google. But I would simply download the NuGet and look at its source code and simply adapt it to fit my needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom view engine and override the methods to adjust the paths.

```
public class LocationAwareViewEngine: RazorViewEngine
{
   protected override IView CreateView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string masterPath)
   {
      // adjust the viewPath and masterPath
      return base.CreateView(controllerContext, viewPath, masterPath);
   }

   protected override IView CreatePartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialPath)
   {
        // adjust the partialPath
        return base.CreatePartialView(controllerContext, partialPath);
   }

   protected override bool FileExists(ControllerContext controllerContext, string virtualPath)
   {
      // adjust the virtualPath
      return base.FileExists(controllerContext, virtualPath);
   }
}
```

**Global.asax.cs**

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new LocationAwareViewEngine());
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple I believe. Use a _viewstart page and a layout page. In the _viewstart page, write your conditional logic to check if the request is from U.A.E and toggle the layout page to use.

```
 If "this is uae request" then
Layout = "layout1.vbhtml"
else
Layout = "layout2.vbhtml"
End if
```

Comment: Dude ! i said my all views will be different not only tha layout page